# Subdomain redirecting me to main domain Apache2

Tags: server, apache2

I have a website running on Apache server. When I try to visit a subdomain, I am redirected to the main domain.

Here is the Apache configuration file:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin waheed@azaanjobs.com
        ServerName azaanjobs.com
        ServerAlias www.azaanjobs.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/azaanjobs/public_html

        <Directory /var/www/azaanjobs/public_html/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/azaanjobs.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/azaanjobs.com/privkey.pem
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin waheed@government-jobs.azaanjobs.com
    ServerName government-jobs.azaanjobs.com
    ServerAlias www.government-jobs.azaanjobs.com.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/government-jobs/public_html/
    
    <Directory /var/www/government-jobs/public_html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Apache will try to match a web request with the configured domains in the order they appear in the file system *and* within the configuration files. As a general rule of thumb, it's better to have subdomains handled before the main site, which should be configured to act as a "catch-all" for any traffic that is unhandled.

With this in mind, your configuration file could be updated to look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin waheed@government-jobs.azaanjobs.com
    ServerName government-jobs.azaanjobs.com
    ServerAlias www.government-jobs.azaanjobs.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/government-jobs/public_html/
    
    <Directory /var/www/government-jobs/public_html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin waheed@azaanjobs.com
        ServerName azaanjobs.com
        ServerAlias www.azaanjobs.com *.azaanjobs.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/azaanjobs/public_html

        <Directory /var/www/azaanjobs/public_html/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/azaanjobs.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/azaanjobs.com/privkey.pem
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**Notes:**

1. the updated configuration file replaces the incorrect `www.government-jobs.azaanjobs.com.com` value for `ServerAlias` with a proper `.com` reference
2. a `*.azaanjobs.com` alias was added to the main domain to ensure any "unexpected" traffic is captured and routed to a probable location
3. there does not seem to be any configuration on the main site for `*:80`, which could be an issue if the something in front of the server is not converting non-SSL traffic to use SSL
4. the subdomain is still listening on port `8080`, so this will need to be updated to `*:80` before visitors can see the site without specifying the port in their browser

Remember to restart Apache after changing the configuration file:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

This should give you what you need

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.
Subdomain is working now but when I change *:80 of main domain to azaanjobs.com:80, website isn't working.

Comment: You can have multiple sites defined with `*:80`. There's no need to change that. Apache will use the first matching reference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. it really helped me.

Comment: I've created one more domain, it is not reading index.html file i changes the permissions also.

Comment: <VirtualHost cvmaker.azaanjobs.com:80>
    ServerAdmin waheed@azaanjobs.com
    ServerName cvmaker.azaanjobs.com
    ServerAlias www.cvmaker.azaanjobs.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/cvmaker/public_html/
    
    <Directory /var/www/cvmaker/public_html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/cverror.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/cvaccess.log combined

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.cvmaker.azaanjobs.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =cvmaker.azaanjobs.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

Comment: <VirtualHost governement-jobs.azaanjobs.com:80>
    ServerAdmin waheed@government-jobs.azaanjobs.com
    ServerName government-jobs.azaanjobs.com
    ServerAlias www.government-jobs.azaanjobs.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/government-jobs/public_html/
    
    <Directory /var/www/government-jobs/public_html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

Comment: ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/govterror.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/govtaccess.log combined

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.government-jobs.azaanjobs.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =government-jobs.azaanjobs.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

Comment: It is not reading any files present in /var/www/cvmaker/public_html/